# Rails 4. jQuery, Acts_as_list, Nested Model, Updating position in controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use rails 4, the acts_as_list gem, and jQuery to sort items(pages) in a table owned by a (scrape). I think my problem may be in the controller method, any help would be really appreciated. The sorting works fine on the front end, the trs move up and down exactly like the railscasts shows. But its not updating the position, after refresh it goes back to how it was.

Here is my controller method sort

```
def sort
  @scrape = Scrape.find(params[:scrape_id])
  @pages = @scrape.pages

  @pages.each_with_index do |id, index|
    Page.where(position: id).update_all({position: index+1})
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```

Here is my view

```
= form_for @scrape do |f|
  %p    
    = f.label :url
    = f.text_field :website

  %table#pages
    %tbody{"data-update-url" => sort_scrape_pages_url(@scrape)}
      = f.fields_for :pages, @pages do |page_type|
        = content_tag_for :tr, page_type.object do
          %td=page_type.object.position     

          %td               
            = link_to page_type.object.url, scrape_page_path(@scrape, page_type.object.id)
          %td               
            = page_type.collection_select :page_type, ["Service Page", "Homepage","About Us", "Contact Us", "Informational", "Sitemap", "Privacy Policy", "Terms", "Blog"], :to_s, :humanize    
  = f.submit "Submit"
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#pages tbody').sortable
  axis: 'y'
  update: ->
    $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

And here is what my console said happened, I dono if this will help anyone but here it is.

```
 Started POST "/scrapes/3/pages/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-19 18:28:56 -0700
 Processing by PagesController#sort as */*
 Parameters: {"page"=>["18", "17", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"], "scrape
 _pages_attributes_0"=>["id"], "scrape_pages_attributes_1"=>["id"], "scrape_pages
 _attributes_2"=>["id"], "scrape_pages_attributes_3"=>["id"], "scrape_pages_attri
 butes_4"=>["id"], "scrape_pages_attributes_5"=>["id"], "scrape_pages_attributes_
 6"=>["id"], "scrape_pages_attributes_7"=>["id"], "scrape_id"=>"3"}
 Scrape Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "scrapes".* FROM "scrapes" WHERE "scrapes"."id" =
 $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
 Page Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."scrape_id" = $
 1 ORDER BY position ASC  [["scrape_id", 3]]
   SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "pages" SET "position" = 1 WHERE "pages"."id" = 17
   SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "pages" SET "position" = 2 WHERE "pages"."id" = 18
   SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "pages" SET "position" = 3 WHERE "pages"."id" = 19
   SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "pages" SET "position" = 4 WHERE "pages"."id" = 20
   SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "pages" SET "position" = 5 WHERE "pages"."id" = 21
   SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "pages" SET "position" = 6 WHERE "pages"."id" = 22
   SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "pages" SET "position" = 7 WHERE "pages"."id" = 23
   SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "pages" SET "position" = 8 WHERE "pages"."id" = 24
 Rendered text template (0.0ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in my controller. My working sort method is below.

```
def sort
  params[:page].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Page.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
  end
  render nothing: true  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are finding position by id that is wrong, but you need to find Record by id

So your method, you need to replace your code

```
@pages.each_with_index do |id, index|
  Page.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @SSR, the final adjustments to get it to work were.


 `(params[:page].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Page.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
  end)`